# How to return blank view in C# MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to return a for a certain controller a blank page.

By blank, i mean blank!. with no Site.Master contents.

How?
Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This will return an empty view

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want no html or content, just return `null` from your action method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to return a page that does not inherit from your master page? If so then in your view page, do the below

```
@{
     Layout = null;     
 }
```